# Why/how is it possible to call class methods of a model on a collection/array returned by a relationship?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

So I came across an interesting bit of code today and it caught my attention. I didn't think this was possible. The line of code was:

```
@post.comments.approved_comments
```

Looks alright, right? But what is really happening is that the `approved_comments` method is being called on an instance of an `Array` object that is returned by a `has_many` relationship (i.e., a post has many comments). What's even more interesting is that `approved_comments` is a class method defined on the `Comment` model.

What has me a bit perplexed is I thought you can't chain off a relationship, not directly at least because a relationship returns an `Array`, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. I've asked a question related to this before and the answer that was given to me is that you can chain off a relationship by using the `scoped` method or one of the many methods that are added to array because of the relationship (i.e., [Section 4.3.1 Methods Added by has_many](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has_many)).

What also has me perplexed is that `approved_comments` is a method that we wrote; it is not a method added by the `has_many` relationship method. So how is it possible that I am able to access it? Even more confusing, how is it that I am able to access it off an `Array` object?

There is, of course, some magic going on. I'm wondering if someone could point me to some documentation or if any experts  have an answer to this. Not a big issue because it seems to work rather nicely, but I'd really like to know how just to educate myself.

Thanks for the help in advance!

### Code

#### Post

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end
```

#### Comment

```
class Comment
  def self.approved_comments
    where(:approved => true)
  end
end
```

#### Usage

```
@post.comments.approved_comments
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with ActiveRecord's way of loading a query. It doesn't execute until you call a method on the object. As a result, it can build the entire query more efficiently. HOWEVER, what you are trying to do is more easily accomplished using a scope:

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  scope :approved_comments, where(:approved => true)
end
```

Now you can do Comment.approved_comments to get ALL approved comments or @post.comments.approved_comments to get approved comments for a Post.

Further more, a scope can take optional parameters. If you wanted to get all posts approved since a User's last visit (for example):

```
class Comment
  scope :approved_since, lambda{ |date| where(['approved_at > ?', date]) }
end
```

Then you could call: `@post.comments.approved_since(@user.last_login)` for example

Look at the [Rails ActiveRecord Named Scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi Seth, thanks for the response. Regarding using methods vs. scopes, there is really no advantage to using a scope over a method other than less lines of code and a declarative style of coding. I've chosen to heed the advice of this article, *Named Scopes Are Dead* (http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/).

Comment: Regarding what is returned by `has_many`, I am not sure if what you're saying is actually the case. All documentation says that a collection object is returned, meaning that the SQL is being executed. I think there might be some confusion with the new changes to the query interface in Rails 3, more specifically that queries now return an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation object and do not execute until `all`, `first`, `last` is called or the object is treated like an enumerable. The simple fact that `@post.comments.class` returns an Array proves that an ActiveRecord::Relation is not returned.

Answer (score 1):

This one here explains **exactly** what you're asking http://railscasts.com/episodes/5-using-with-scope